# How do I parse a string delimited by / into an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have tried several methods of parsing a string and adding the elements to an array with using a `/` as a delimiter. I know I will eventually need to use stod(). Can anyone point me in the right direction? I will need to parse the string rec.

```
 void make_record() {

        int size = 4;
        double* record = nullptr;
        string rec;
        cout << "Enter record of items separated by a space " << endl;
        cout << "Item ID/Quantity/WholesaleCost/RetailCost" << endl;
        cin >> rec; // string to parse
        //Current: 12345 27.5 82.4 5.3
        //Goal: 12345/27.5/82.4/5.3
       
        //current approach
        record = new double[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cin >> record[i]; 
        }

        //What I have tried - probably very wrong
        string delimiter = "/";

        size_t pos = 0;
        std::string token;
        while ((pos = rec.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
            token = rec.substr(0, pos);
            rec.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
            record[pos] = stod(token);
            cout << record[pos];
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: Can you give a little more detail about what you want to accomplish ("parsing a string into an array" and "I will eventually need to use stod" are pretty vague) and what the program is doing _instead_ of what you want?

Comment: I guess he wants slashes '/' to be used as number separators. Not just whitespaces.

Comment: @m2j yes that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really not a lot more complicated than your current approach.

```
    // better approach
    record = new double[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        char slash;
        cin >> record[i] >> slash; 
    }
    cin >> record[size - 1];
```

The `slash` variable reads (and discards) the slashes in your input. Because the last number is not followed by a slash, it must be read separately, after the main loop.

Now this approach doesn't do any error checking at all, but given correct input it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize strtok or strtok_s function, and can directly convert them into an array.
For reference you can visit : https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).